# Questions to be flaged as Low Quality

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been reviewing from past few days for low quality posts weather to close them or not. But I feel it unfair when the low quality is reported especially for questions which are created the same day or you can say not even few hours before the poster has posted.

I feel there should be a time limitation where a question is to be reported as low quality as the Author may not be able to explain his question properly but if there are comment posted that what more things are required he may do so. Because at the end of the day the author may require the solution he is looking for.

Whats your point of view in this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A low quality question is low quality today AND tomorrow.
If the OP cannot explain properly his problem, that's a low quality question.
If there are comments posted after the question is closed and the OP edits the question to provide proper info the question will appear automatically in the the reopen votes queue.
If the question is not edited but there is valuable info in the comments the question is still low quality. Crucial info should not reside only in comments.

Conclusion:
I don't think there should be a time limitation for reporting questions as low quality.

Comment: As a mod I will try to comment if closing a fresh question when it is from a new user, to invite him or her to comment / edit.