# A reminder to be more kind to young questions regarding flagging for close

Tags: discussion

I just did go through the review for close queue, and found half of the questions there were valid, and I was even able to answer them(not real good answers, that would have needed a bit more time, but that's not the point), the point is, they are answerable, and therefore valid questions.

Keeping the site clean is great, but keep in mind how a new user feels, if a question gets closed just hours after it got created.

Also, just because the question does not contain enough information to be answerable for you, it can be enough information for someone else to answer. Because sometimes, the topic is just so simple, that there is not needed more.

Example: [How to Know that on which channel the coupon has been used in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191315/how-to-know-that-on-which-channel-the-coupon-has-been-used-in-magento/191387#191387)

Comment: Did you have a typo in the title: 'jung'? Also, an answerable question doesn't mean it deserves to be answered (e.g. many off-topic questions can be answered). In this case, it's too broad, there are too many possible answers to fulfill what OP wants.

Comment: ahh yes, this was a typo in the title.. 
For the example case I would say the opposite, the area of this topic is so super small, that any additional information would not change anything on the possible answers.

Comment: I agree: for die hard Magento developers and admins, some questions might seem not valid. But to help out those that starting to use Magento, these questions are still valid questions and the answers to those questions might help them to become experienced developers, eventually.

Comment: This applies to any SE site IMO. Trigger-happy moderators so ready to close a question because at first glance it seems to be lacking information but then myself or someone else accurately and completely answers it. Yes, yes... I'm aware; SE has guidelines and it's not for everybody.

Comment: I had the same question in [mind] . https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/questions-to-be-flaged-as-low-quality